# Connect ReactJS file in Main.go

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, go

I am trying to develop a web application with ReactJS and a Go server. The web app works when I connect ReactJS file with Node.js, but it shows an error on the output when I connect ReactJS file with the Go server.

output:

> "404 page not found"

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var items = []*Item{}

// Item representing the todo
type Item struct {
    ID   string `json:"item_id"`
    Name string `json:"item_name"`
}

func main() {
    //r := http.NewServeMux()
     r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.PathPrefix("client/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("client/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".client/"))))
    r.HandleFunc("/api/new-item", addItemHandler)
    fmt.Println("Running server on port :3000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}

func addItemHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    item := &Item{}
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(item)
    items = append(items, item)
}
```

my file structure:

```
appName/main.go
appName/client/src/App.js
```

I would like the web app to load `App.js` when I run `main.go`

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the directory really ".client"? `http.Dir(".client/")` Or is it  client `http.Dir("./client")`

Comment: If i would direct to App.js, shouldn't it be "client/"? Anyways I am really new to reactjs and go, so I don't really know whether that's the way to connect to my .js file

Comment: If you're trying to serve the App.js from appName directory, then http.Dir should be either "client" or "./client", not ".client", and you should load it as /client/src/App.js. Also for the pathPrefix, I think it should be "/client", but I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: thanks for the info. I've tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What are you requesting? It should be localhost:3030/src/App.js ; (I'm wondering if you're requesting localhost:3030/App.js...)

Comment: looks like it should actually be `localhost:3000/client/src/App.js`, however you should know that this won't execute your javascript but instead write it to the response so you'll just recieve a JS file as plaintext and I do not think that's what you want? If you're trying to render a react component you should serve an HTML page with your js included. If you really do want to serve a plaintext JS file then I have this working using `http.NewServeMux` and can share that code with you